# Spring boot webflux returning HTML content

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

Trying to build a hosted page like Payment application where the payment URL will be embedded on our website inside IFrame which will display the payment HTML.

Is it possible to do the same using Spring boot webeflux? Not sure how to return HTML from Spring boot webflux.

Basically,  There will be frontend in which user will upload the HTML and the same will be stored in DB and each upload will have a unique ID. User can just embed this unique id with the URL in their website and thecorresponding HTML from DB should be loaded in the embedded area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an option (I don't tell that it's the best option, it depends on your use case)

```
@RestController
public class HtmlViewController {

    @GetMapping(path = "/{pageId}", produces = TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
    public Mono<String> get(@PathVariable String pageId,
                            @RequestParam(required = false) Map<String, String> requestParams) {
        return getPage(pageId, requestParams);
    }

    private Mono<String> getPage(String pageId, Map<String, String> requestParams) {
        // `getTemplate` - fetch html template from your storage in a reactive way, should return `Mono<String>`
        return getTemplate(pageId) 
                .flatMap(htmlTemplate -> {
                    // apply request parameters to your html page, like replacing placeholders with links, user name etc.
                });
    }
```

For that you need to add the following dependencies: `spring-boot-starter-webflux` and `springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui` (it's optional, but with that you will be able to test your response using swagger).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Edited my question with the detail. The HTML data will be served from DB based on the pageID. Each pageID will have totally a different HTML content.

Answer (score 1):

Returning HTML directly would be odd / ill-advised (possible, but not recommended.)

The better thing to do would be to use Thymeleaf or similar to create your presentation layer, then on your spring controller, set reactive properties on the model, eg:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public String index(final Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("elements", new ReactiveDataDriverContextVariable(repository.findAll()));
    model.addAttribute("anotherattribute", Mono.just(6));
    //...and so on
    return "index";
}
```

This will then reactively populate your model with the correct context before displaying the desired HTML.

Comment: Requirement is to return dynamic data as the HTML content will be different for different user.

Comment: @user1578872 *Completely* different, or just different enough that you can template it? If it's the former, you could just use different template files based on the user. If it's the latter, you can use the same template file and just populate the associated model dynamically.

Comment: Just updated my query again. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @user1578872 I'd be weary of storing & loading raw HTML from a database - but if you're sure that's what you want, you probably want to use Vasiliy's answer.

Comment: Sorry, but returning HTML from a controller is not odd, it's a valid use case with many very reasonable applications